# How to input data in one React component and have it render in another?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I'm learning React using JSX and ES6 and I've got a pretty decent handle on how to create components and route to different views using ReactRouter4.

What I still haven't been able to figure out is for example how i can create an Admin page where I input the details of a work for my portfolio and have all the works render on the another page, presumably Portfolio page.

Here's what I've got.

`App.js` loads the `Portfolio.js` component

```
import React from 'react';

import Navigation from './Navigation';
import Title from './Title';
import Portfolio from './Portfolio';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-12">
              <Navigation />
              <Title title="kuality.io"/>
              <section className="app">
                <Portfolio works={this.props.works} />
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

The `Portfolio.js` component has a constructor to bind a unique method named `addWork()`, the React methods `componentWillMount()` and `componentWillUnmount()` to handle state, and the default `render()`. One more thing to mention about this component is that it's calling a component called `../base` which has all the details to an online DB via Firebase. So if that's relevant as to where it is place, then take that into consideration otherwise don't sweat it.

```
import React from 'react';

import Work from './Work';
import Admin from './Admin';
import base from '../base';

class Portfolio extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addWork = this.addWork.bind(this);

    // getInitialState
    this.state = {
      works: {}
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.ref = base.syncState(`/works`
      , {
        context: this,
        state: 'works'
      })
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    base.removeBinding(this.ref);
  }
  addWork(work) {
    // update our state
    const works = {...this.state.works};
    // add in our new works with a timestamp in seconds since Jan 1st 1970
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    works[`work-${timestamp}`] = work;
    // set state
    this.setState({ works });
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <section className="portfolio">
          <h3>Portfolio</h3>
          <ul className="list-of-work">
            {
              Object
              .keys(this.state.works)
              .map(key => <Work key={key} details={this.state.works[key]}/>)
            }
          </ul>
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

Inside of the `Object` i'm mapping through the `Work` component that is just a list item I have made another component for and isn't really relevant in the question.

Finally I have the `Admin.js` and `AddWorkForm.js` components. I abstracted the `AddWorkForm.js` so that I could use it elsewhere if need be, basically the main idea behind React Components, so that's why I chose to do it that way.

```
import React from 'react';

import Title from './Title';
import AddWorkForm from './AddWorkForm';

class Admin extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addWork = this.addWork.bind(this);

    // getInitialState
    this.state = {
      works: {}
    };
  }

  addWork(work) {
    // update our state
    const works = {...this.state.works};
    // add in our new works with a timestamp in seconds since Jan 1st 1970
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    works[`work-${timestamp}`] = work;
    // set state
    this.setState({ works });
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-12">
              <Title title="Admin"/>
              <section className="admin">
                <AddWorkForm addWork={this.addWork} />
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Admin;
```

and the `AddWorkForm.js` component which is basically a form that `onSubmit` creates and object and resets the form

```
import React from 'react';

class AddWorkForm extends React.Component {
  createWork(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Creating some work');
    const work = {
      name: this.name.value,
      desc: this.desc.value,
      image: this.image.value
    }
    this.props.addWork(work);
    this.workForm.reset();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form ref={(input) => this.workForm = input} className="work-edit form-group" onSubmit={(e) => this.createWork(e)}>
        <input ref={(input) => this.name = input} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Work Title"/>
        <textarea ref={(input) => this.desc = input} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Work Description"></textarea>
        <input ref={(input) => this.image = input} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Work Image"/>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">+Add Work</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default AddWorkForm;
```

Here is the file that includes where I'm using `ReactRouter`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
// To render one method from a package user curly brackets, you would have to know what method you wan though
import { BrowserRouter, Match, Miss} from 'react-router';

import './css/normalize.css';
import './css/bootstrap.css';
import './css/style.css';

// import '../js/bootstrap.js';

import App from './components/App';
import WorkItem from './components/WorkItem';
import Capability from './components/Capability';
import Connect from './components/Connect';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';
import Admin from './components/Admin';

const Root  = ()=> {
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Match exactly pattern="/" component={App} />
        <Match pattern="/work/:workId" component={WorkItem} />
        <Match exactly pattern="/capability" component={Capability} />
        <Match exactly pattern="/connect" component={Connect} />
        <Match exactly pattern="/admin" component={Admin} />
        <Miss component={NotFound} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

render (<Root />, document.querySelector('#main'));
```

So here's what I've tried and failed to accomplish, and it's likely some kind of `this.props` solution that I haven't been able to define, I need to create the `work` in `Admin.js` component, which creates the object and then have it throw that object to `Portfolio.js` component so it can render it via the `Work.js` component and it doesn't add the object to the DB.

This works when i put all the components on the same page, which isn't ideal because then anyone accessing my Portfolio could add a work. Sure I could start the process of learning authentication and how to make that component appear or disappear based on user credentials, but I'd much rather also learn the very valuable skill of being able to have my admin page on a separate view all together because I see another application for learning to do so.

Would love to hear others opinions on this and where they may be able to determine I'm failing here.

Btw, I realize I have other components like `Nav.js` and `Title.js` but they are not necessary in order to illustrate the example.

Thank you.

Comment: TLDR. You can't exchange data between two components that are at the same level or in different branches. You need either a parent component that stores them or something like Redux.

Comment: Echoing what @zurfyx is saying. Storing the state in a parent component of both Admin and Portfolio is probably a good first approach. Out of curiousity, are you actually using react router somewhere? Can you show the code where your Match components are?

Comment: @zurfyx Ok I will look in to that.

Comment: @azium I have updated the example to include the index.js where I am using the Match, Miss, and BrowserRouter methods from ReactRouter

Comment: @zurfyx That makes perfect sense I didn't realize that Portfolio and Admin are siblings, and that the other components like `Work`, and `AddWorkForm` are descendants of Portfolio and Admin. So by wrapping both of these inside of App perhaps and having the data at the App component level, this in theory should be able to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass components as props and when using React Router you can have [named components](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#components-1).

For data sharing between siblings is better advised to have the data on a parent component although you could use context, but this [is not advised](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#why-not-to-use-context) and may be unacessible on future versions.

If you need to create something on another component (don't know why) you could pass a function that would render it.